# How to extract a corrupted zip file?

Tags: zip, gzip, unzip

I compressed some zip files into another zip file. Later, when I tried to extract it, I got the following message:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: does this help https://superuser.com/questions/23290/terminal-tool-linux-for-repair-corrupted-zip-files ?

Answer (score 5):

The `zip` tool provides the `--fix` (or `-F`) option to try repairing corrupt zip files. For very damaged archives, there is the `-FF` option. You can thus recover data from a corrupt zip file with a command like ([reference](https://superuser.com/questions/23290/terminal-tool-linux-for-repair-corrupted-zip-files)):

```
zip -FF corrupted.zip --out new.zip
```

Only undamaged files can be recovered: some files may be missing.

Answer (score 3):

Because:

```
zip -FF corrupted.zip --out new.zip
```

ended with error:

```
zip warning: no end of stream entry found: DCIM/Camera/VID_20230128_173302.mp4
    zip warning: rewinding and scanning for later entries
```

therefore, I ran

```
zip -FF new.zip --out new2.zip
```

which again ended with the message:

```
Central Directory found...
EOCDR found ( 1 4156974377)...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 0a 07 on disk 0 at 4195187925
    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 09 04 on disk 0 at 4241474727
    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 04 0a on disk 0 at 4248545602
    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 07 08 on disk 0 at 4257152005
    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 09 0c on disk 0 at 4270143948
    zip warning: skipping this signature...
    zip warning: unexpected signature 50 4b 09 03 on disk 0 at 4288941105
    zip warning: skipping this signature...
```

but this time, the archive could be opened and file restored.